# Splitting an href and putting the html into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, split, href

I want to send this HTML, minus "/modal" into a variable:

```
<span class="detailsLink"><object><a href="/content/modal/30OffLucky" class="js-modal btn-secondary">DETAILS</a></object></span>
```

How can I add to this line to make it work?:

```
var eemailDetails = $('.detailsLink').html();
```

This ends up taking out /modal before it passes it into the variable:

```
var eemailDetails = $('.detailsLink a').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace('/modal', '');
}).html();
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It looks like the code you've given does what you want already.

Comment: @mattsven I'm sorry as I likely have not explained it correctly. I do not want the HTML to change on the site when the js runs, I only want the "/modal" to be cut out when passed into the variable.

Comment: create the variable, set its value to `this.href`, then do the same replace on your new variable. Bada bing, bada boom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement should be made on the value retrieved instead of on the element's attribute.

So to retrieve the HTML markup **including the targeted element**, the [outerHTML property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) can be used.

```js
// Get the whole HTML
var eemailDetails = $('.detailsLink')[0].outerHTML;

// Remove /modal
eemailDetails = eemailDetails.replace('/modal', '');


console.log("The attribute unchanged: "+$('.detailsLink a').attr("href"));
console.log("The HTML retrieved: "+eemailDetails);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="detailsLink"><object><a href="/content/modal/30OffLucky" class="js-modal btn-secondary">DETAILS</a></object></span>
```

Comment: Yes let's forget about the .each as this is the only link to worry about. But how do I get the whole line of HTML into that variable? I'm not sure on how to read your two console.log's.

Comment: I want 

    var eemailDetails = <span class="detailsLink"><object><a href="/content/30OffLucky" class="js-modal btn-secondary">DETAILS</a></object></span>

Comment: So wait, you want the eemailDetails to contain the entire DOM structure, with the href updated? Wow. Disregard my answer. And in future, be a little clearer...

Answer (score 1):

So the each works fine, and I save the variable as a data-attribute on the element itself. Later, when it gets clicked, I can recall that data attribute as needed. Hope this helps!

```js
$('.detailsLink a').each(function(){
  var changedLink = this.href.replace('/modal', '');
    $(this).data("changedLink", changedLink)
});

$(".detailsLink a").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var returnEl = $(this).parents(".detailsLink").clone();
  returnEl.find("a").attr("href", $(this).data("changedLink") );
  
  console.log(returnEl[0].outerHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="detailsLink"><object><a href="/content/modal/30OffLucky" class="js-modal btn-secondary">DETAILS</a></object></span>
<span class="detailsLink"><object><a href="/content/modal/30OffNotSoLucky" class="js-modal btn-secondary">More DETAILS</a></object></span>
<span class="detailsLink"><object><a href="/content/modal/HaveAFrog" class="js-modal btn-secondary">Yet More DETAILS!</a></object></span>
```

Comment: Sorry Snowmonkey for the downvote... Re-reading it, I see that you took care of the `.each()` loop part of the question. I should not have downvoted it. Please edit it (add 1 char) so I can undown it. ;)

Comment: I misread the question, though -- it wasn't the link itself that the OP wanted returned, but the element with its link updated. Rather than blow away the existing el, I'm now cloning it and able to return THAT. Thanks for explaining, though, @LouysPatriceBessette.